# Can Google Cloud Build be triggered by new Docker image in Container Registry?

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build

I'm setting up a CI/CD using Google's cloud tools, and was expecting to have a trigger condition "when new image is uploaded to Container Registry".

The use case is separating deployment from source (repo). Source would push Docker images and deployment would deploy them to a test stage.

But Cloud Build only provides me a trigger choice between three source repos. [link](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/automate-builds)

What would you use for test, QA and production deployment of Docker images, in a GKE context?

Comment: It looks like Cloud Build is still in Beta and does not support Cloud Repository as of yet. I strongly recommend opening a feature request to have this added in. Considering the repos they do include, I'm surprised GCR is not already there

Comment: Good advice. Google issue management details are laid out here https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers and existing Cloud Build issues are here https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/5226584 

I filed this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122382955 . Please visit and add stars if you wish it to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

Meanwhile, there is a solution but it's a lillte cumbersome.

As most of you probably know, GCR stores its images into a Bucket, it is possible then to write a Cloud Function that is triggered whenever a changes occurs in the Bucket (look at the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage)).

Your Cloud Function will then run the trigger by calling either the Google Cloud SDK client either the rest [API](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/run).