# How to trigger Google Cloud Build, based on a change in a Docker registry

Tags: continuous-deployment, google-cloud-build

It's obvious the short answer is "it cannot be done". Google Cloud Console currently provides these as options for a build trigger:

> [image]

Is there, however, some workaround that I have missed - or knowledge that Docker registry might be supported as a trigger during early 2019?

What I look for is separation of the "source" and "deployment" repos (for business and organizational reasons). I would like one team to "drop off" logic as a Docker image and another repo (and team) to pull it to deployments.

Comment: Had already filed this prior to winter vacation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748538/can-google-cloud-build-be-triggered-by-new-docker-image-in-container-registry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Google Cloud Build be triggered by new Docker image in Container Registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748538/can-google-cloud-build-be-triggered-by-new-docker-image-in-container-registry)